# Why I can't find any native method in printIn() implementation?

Tags: java, io, implementation

I walk through the program of below statement:

```
System.out.println("foo");
```

In my understanding, all functionality Java provides should ultimately call system specific API but I can only see, in println() implementation, calling ordinary methods in Writer/BufferWriter/PrintStream. Where do I get wrong?

Comment: You're not looking deep enough. How does the JVM interact with the platform it's functioning on? That depends on the JVM and the platform obviously, and that's a hard one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't look into the source code, because it is easy to get lost in the forest of decorator streams. Use a debugger, and find the code where the text actually appears on the console.

EDIT: On my computer this happens in sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder. I didn't go deeper, because I would need the source code for this class, and the source of sun.* classes is not among the standard Java sources. But you can download the OpenJDK sources, associate with the class file, and with enough patience you can find the secret of System.out.println...

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code, you can see that `System.out` is by default initialized to `public final static PrintStream out = nullPrintStream();`.

This code just produces a null object. Obviously, the VM is stepping in somewhere and setting up the stream.

Some further digging found the line of code:

```
private static native void setOut0(PrintStream out);
```

This line is called by the public `setOut()` you're probably more familiar with.